# File path has special character \N

Tags: python, ironpython

I am working on copying a file from one location to another. This is easy, using `shutil.copy`. Everything was fine until a special "source" came.

The path of the file is like this:

```
c:\install\NewCustomer\fire.exe
```

Now whenever I execute this, it throws an error:

```
    'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 975: malformed \N character escape
  at IronPython.Runtime.LiteralParser.ParseString (System.Char[] text, Int32 start, Int32 length, Boolean isRaw, Boolean isUni, Boolean normalizeLineEndings) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Tokenizer.MakeStringToken (Char quote, Boolean isRaw, Boolean isUnicode, Boolean isBytes, Boolean isTriple, Int32 start, Int32 length) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Tokenizer.ContinueString (Char quote, Boolean isRaw, Boolean isUnicode, Boolean isBytes, Boolean isTriple, Int32 startAdd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Tokenizer.ReadString (Char quote, Boolean isRaw, Boolean isUni, Boolean isBytes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Tokenizer.Next () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Tokenizer.GetNextToken () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.FetchLookahead () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.NextToken () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.MaybeEat (TokenKind kind) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.FinishAssignments (IronPython.Compiler.Ast.Expression right) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseExprStmt () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSmallStmt () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSimpleStmt () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseTryStatement () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassOrFuncBody () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFuncDef () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSuite () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassOrFuncBody () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseClassDef () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFileWorker (Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFile (Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.ParseAndBindAst (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.CompilerContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompilePythonCode (Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit sourceUnit, Microsoft.Scripting.CompilerOptions options, Microsoft.Scripting.ErrorSink errorSink) [0x00000]
```

It's because of special character "\N". I know if I write the following code, it will work:

```
r"c:\install\NewCustomer\fire.exe"
```

But the problem is the source path is generated dynamically, so until runtime I don't know if I have to handle this special character. Is there any way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Here I thought this was going to be an "I'm reading a bunch of filenames out of a file/stdin/etc. on Unix and one of them has an embedded `'\n'` character in the actual filename" problem, but instead it's just "I decided to use Python source as my serialization format for some reason, and I don't know how to quote or escape things", which is much less fun.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you generating Python code for the paths? Generate the paths into a text file and then read them in.

`\n` is not the only special character that could cause problems your way - you likely have to use raw strings always.

Answer (score -2):

```
yourvariable.strip()
```

if your run that on your variable when your calling it, it should remove the new line characters.